# How to grep a directory based on the timestamp of the file?

Tags: linux, unix, grep

I am running the following command in a data directory:

```
$  grep -r '0xdataH2O' ./
```

There are a lot of files in this folder, and I'd only like to grep recent files. Is there a way to do something like the following:

```
$ grep -r '0xdataH2O' ./<$files_modified_within_last_two_days>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
find . -type f -mtime -2 -exec grep -H 0xdataH20 {} \;
```

Comment: cool. What is `grep -H` ? I couldn't find`-H` on the man page: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/grep.1p.html

Comment: Oh, here's a better one: `-H, --with-filename` `Print the file name for each match.  This is the default when there is more than one file to search.  This is a GNU extension.` https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/grep.1.html